# HTML5Mode, AngularJS and Grunt Build Control

Tags: angularjs, grunt-build-control

Hoping someone can answer this because I'm struggling...

I have an angular js app that was build with the yo-angular generator. All works fine with deploying through grunt build control, as long as I'm not using the #-free "html5mode."

However, once I enable html5mode to remove the # from my routing and then deploy, my app on github pages doesn't point to the correct source for its scripts and such... For instance, I'm getting a 404 error because it's looking for http://{{user name}}.github.io/scripts/{{name of file}}, instead of http://{{user name}}.github.io/**{{app name}}**/scripts/{{name of file}}

How can I get it to point to the correct directory?

Hope this makes sense. I'll share more if needed!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to configure the server. The configuration change will depend on what technology you are using to host the app on the server. [How to configure your server to work with html5mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)